# jQuery - javascript error - cisco web vpn

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a very unique situation.

We use a Cisco Web VPN (don't know the exact name) here at work.

If I try to use the web pages I've developed, the javascript is broken.

**I have tracked it down to this:**

When using the Cisco Web VPN it will actually rewrite some of the HTML/JavaScript code. 
For instance, at the very beginning of the source it has stuck the following:

```
<script  id='CSCO_GHOST' src="/+CSCOL+/cte.js"></script>
```

This is directly after the `<html>` begin tag (and not inside the `<head>` tags).

Inside of that source, cte.js, there is an error. That error is causing jQuery to not function properly. cte.js is part of Cisco's product and is totally out of my control.

I know how to capture errors with the windows.onerror but that is not working for this situation. The error is occurring before my scripts are loaded into the page.

**Any ideas on how to suppress this error or work around such a thing?**

I had my `<script>` tags in the `<head>` and then moved them to the bottom of the `<body>` and in neither place does it make a difference.

**UPDATE:**
After a bit more looking, it is something in jQuery. I commented out the `<script>` tag for jQuery and the error did not happen. Uncommented, the error came back.

Comment: What is the specific error?  It might be possible to work around in some way.

Comment: They have this code: name.toLowerCase() and name is null.

Comment: I guess I should have said that the error that is thrown is: name is undefined. They didn't check that before calling the toLowerCase().

Comment: As a side note, I hope your IT department has upgraded, because `cte.js` contains a flaw that allows a remote cross-site scripting attack. http://osvdb.org/show/osvdb/55575

Comment: It would be helpful to see chunk of code where that `name.toLowerCase()` is used. You can try debugging it to see why `name` is `undefined` and what exactly caused it (by looking through the call stack).

Comment: out of curiosity, are you attempting to use the packed version of jquery.js? Some scanners/etc find packer-compressed JS as a trojan. If this is the case, use the .min.js version (minified, not packed)

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this question and _explaining_ what seemed like an _unexplainable_ bug!!

Comment: What code have commented out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I had to do to fix the problem. I created a JS file in my web project with the following code:

```
   if ( typeof SegmentHtml != "undefined" ) {
      SegmentHtmlParam.prototype['filter'] = function() {
         var name = null;
         var value = null;
         for (var i = 1; i < this._tokens.length; i++) {
            var token = this._tokens[i];
            if (token.type === ATTR_NAME) {
               name = csco_g_buffer.substring(token.first_index, token.last_index).toUpperCase();
            } else if (token.type === ATTR_VALUE) {
               value = csco_g_buffer.substring(token.first_index, token.last_index);
            };
         };
         var need_processing = false;
         if (ParserClsidName) {
            var tmp = ParserClsidName[this._clsid];
            if (tmp) {
               var proc = tmp[name];
               need_processing = typeof proc != 'undefined';
            };
         };
         /**
         * ERROR ON NEXT LINE: name is null
         */
         if (name!=null && name.toLowerCase() == "csco_proto") {
            this._parent['csco_proto'] = value;
         };
         if (need_processing) { this._parent[name] = value; };
      };    
   };
```

**This is the FIRST javascript file I include in my HTML file.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryCiscoKludge.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW - I would have not been able to find this bug without the use of the new debugger in IE8. FireBug never caught this error but the IE8 debugger did.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this issue as well. It is really messed up for Cisco to just rewrite JS code like that, assuming it'll work for every single code on the web. There are some serious irreversible consequence like scope loss that will screw everything up. Who in their right mind would do that in the name of "security"? And what is preventing us from overriding the JS code they have injected?

Comment: That is exactly what I had to do to work around the error, override one of their own functions.

Comment: hobbyman, could you elaborate which function you overwrite? They seem to be mangling jQuery in a lot of places, how do you know which one to fix?

Thanks!